# Make geolocation work on Safari without Wifi?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, geolocation

I'm simply using this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
```

It works on Chrome, Firefox etc., but not on Safari.

I read that it should work only when the Wifi is enabled.

Is there a way to make it work without needing Wifi? Perhaps using Modernizr?

Using AngularJS, here's my exact code:

```
                $scope.showPosition = function (position) {
                    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                };

                $scope.showError = function (error) {
                    switch (error.code) {
                        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                            $scope.error = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                            break;
                        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                            $scope.error = "Location information is unavailable."
                            break;
                        case error.TIMEOUT:
                            $scope.error = "The request to get user location timed out."
                            break;
                        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                            $scope.error = "An unknown error occurred."
                            break;
                    }
                    $scope.$apply();
                };

                $scope.getLocation = function () {
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($scope.showPosition, $scope.showError);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
                    }
                };

                $scope.getLocation();
```

Without using Wifi, the error thrown is: `Location information is unavailable.`

Comment: I don't believe this is true: geolocation works in Safari but there are a couple of gotchas, not least that the user may have disabled it in their preferences. Have you tested using the live code in the Dive Into HTML5 page? http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html

Comment: Also, are you calling `navigator.getlocation.getCurrentPosition()` without the relevant callbacks and error handlers?

Comment: Updated my post with my exact code. (yes there are callbacks)

Comment: I don't think `Modernizr` will help, that would just indicate whether the current user agent supports geolocation...

Comment: Yes, I just mentioned Modernizr after reading it on a potential solution, but it was clearly just an indication of feature existence. I wonder: "perhaps Modernizr has a trick for it (besides just warning of missing feature), but no :)"

Comment: Anyway, I don't see pure benefit of HTML5 geolocation since it isn't very accurate without using Wifi... And I can't expect user to connect with Wifi only..

Comment: It seems to be very hit and miss in all manner of browsers... when IP-only I wonder whether the relevant services that browsers are using are just not stable enough? e.g. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116986